# Check whether page unload or navigating

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to show an alert message when an user navigate to one page from a page. Is there any event to fire when we navigate to another page. I can't write it in `PageUnload` event as it will fire when I refresh also.

Comment: The chosen answer in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167317/navigate-away-alert-without-saving-modifications , might help. Alert message works well even for refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy to accomplish, you simply need to intercept every anchor link click event and check if the anchor matches the page in question.

Comment: I'm doing a plugin for someone. I cann't control it. they may navigate it normal javascript instead of anchor tag.